# how to Get selected option value within PHP page reload

Tags: php, html-select

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="event_name" class="col-sm-2  col-md-1 col-form-label">Event Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control event" name='event_name' id='event_name'>
            <option value="Option_1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option_2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option_3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="Option_4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="Option_5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>{Event name}</h4>
```

my question is how to get {Event name} when i select any option?

Comment: You somehow need to save selection. If you want selection to be saved on the reload you can use either $_SESSION variable or you can store the value in the cookie via JS upon selection and then read it from `$_COOKIE` variable. Then you just need to add `selected="selected"` in the option which was previously set once you reload the page. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: You can either save the value when the form is sent and you get the value in the $_POST or $_GET vars or use JavaScript to get the value and save it if the form has not been sent. But we need more info to know what do you want.

Comment: And, to be honest, you don't seem having done any effort trying to do it.

Comment: this selected option is not inside {form}. get the value without submitting form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with easily with a session within a form. Just do something at the top like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['form'])) {
   $_SESSION['eName'] = $_GET['event_name'];
}
?>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="event_name" class="col-sm-2  col-md-1 col-form-label">Event Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <form method="GET" action="">
        <select class="form-control event" name='event_name' id='event_name'>
            <option value="Option_1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option_2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option_3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="Option_4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="Option_5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="form">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

<h4><?php if(isset($_SESSION['eName'])) { echo $_SESSION['eName']; }?></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got my answer and it's for without submitting value

```
<?PHP
    $event_name = $_GET['event_name'];
?>

<script>
jQuery(function($){

    $('#event_name').change(function(e){
        let event_name = e.target.value;
        window.location.href = `/wp-admin/admin.php?pageName&event_name=${event_name}`;
    });
}
</script>
```